# Can't connect to remote MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I'm trying to open a connection from my NetBeans IDE to my remote MySQL database. I've put in what I think is the correct parameters in the response fields but when I try to test the connection it gives me this error message:

> Cannot establish a connection to
>
> `jdbc:mysql://198.136.54.104:3306/myedigit_FirstDb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`
>
> using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

[image: screenshot]

Please let me know if you need any more information I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Well, my first guess is that you have incorrect connection parameters specified. Can you connect through some other service to verify the parameters are correct?

Comment: I fixed it. as you said the connection parameters were incorrect once I changed them I was able to log in.

Comment: May be, add an EDIT on your question itself to post the changes that you've made in the Connection String to fix your problem. This helps the others who seek help on similar grounds!

Answer (score 0):

Your host may not allowing remote connection.
You may need to add `Access Host` by Login into your host server and go to `Remote MySql` (I am referring `GoDaddy`)

You need to provide either your IP Address in host or `%` to access remotely from anywhere.

[image]